# Format big query results in python

Tags: python, sql, datetime, split, google-bigquery

Here is my big query:

```
SELECT datestamp, slot, food, price, menu
        FROM `food_table`
        WHERE datestamp BETWEEN 2020-01-01 AND 2020-01-25
```

big query gave me following output:

```
Row((datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'slot-1', None, None, None), {'datestamp': 0, 'slot': 1, 'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'menu': 4})
Row((datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), 'slot-2', None, None, None), {'datestamp': 0, 'slot': 1, 'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'menu': 4})
Row((datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), 'slot-2', None, None, None), {'datestamp': 0, 'slot': 1, 'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'menu': 4})
Row((datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), 'slot-3', None, None, None), {'datestamp': 0, 'slot': 1, 'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'menu': 4})
Row((datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), 'slot-1', None, None, None), {'datestamp': 0, 'slot': 1, 'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'menu': 4})
```

So far I have done something like this for formating:

```
report_data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict())
 for row in query_job:
     date=row['datestamp']
     report_data[row['slot']][date] = row
 print(report_data)
```

But it doesn't seems to be my expected format. Expected format:

```
{'slot-1': defaultdict(None, {'2020-01-01': {'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'slot': 'slot-1', 'menu': 4, 'date': '2020-01-01'},{'2020-01-03': {'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'slot': 'slot-1', 'menu': 4, 'date': '2020-01-03'}),
{'slot-2': defaultdict(None, {'2020-01-02': {'food': 4, 'price': 6, 'slot': 'slot-2', 'menu': 4, 'date': '2020-01-02'},
{'slot-3': defaultdict(None, {'2020-01-02': {'food': 2, 'price': 3, 'slot': 'slot-2', 'menu': 4, 'date': '2020-01-02'},
```

Comment: And ? What's your question ? What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what are you trying to do. What is your question? What are you trying to do? Where is the error? Did you find some error in BigQuery?

Comment: show the query that you used to produce the result - so we will help you to adjust/fix it to get what you need. it looks simple to me

Comment: i have attached the query that I used to produce the result. Now please help me to fix it. Thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dataframe from the query_job results as follows:

```
result = query_job.result()
output = result.to_dataframe()

# output = {i: dict(row.items()) for i, row in enumerate(result)}
```